# AndroidStudio 2.1 creates empty activity without ActionBar

Tags: android-studio

As the title says, Android studio 2.1 creates the following code in a empty activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

All the boilerplate required to setup an ActionBar is missing, and typing and creating everything is cumbersome. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that, put the following code in `onCreate()`, before you set content view.

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Or you can define your theme like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863676/android-activity-without-actionbar).