# How to hide a navigation bar for splash activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am new in a Android. I would like to hide a navigation bar only for splash activity.

I have written a below code to hide Action Bar. But this code is unable to hide my navigation bar -

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

And this is my splash_activity -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#b7eaea"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And This is my Java code. Please let me know if any changes.

```
package com.example.user.boat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 8000;
    private GifImageView gif;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        gif = (GifImageView)findViewById(R.id.loader);

        try{
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("splash" +
                    ".gif");
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            gif.setBytes(bytes);
            gif.startAnimation();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent home = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(home);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the parent attribute as "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" then add a custom toolbar for other activities

Comment: I tried this. This is not able hide my navigation bar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: I tried this. This is not able hide my navigation bar.

Comment: Have you applied "AppTheme.NoActionBar" to your SplashActivity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Have you run your code on real device? or you just see the preview in Android Studio?

Comment: On my real device

Comment: That's strange! Post your activity.java too

Comment: Yes. I have posted.

Comment: Check if you comply this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25863690/4224024

Answer (score 0):

You can set it programatically like this :

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Put these two lines of code before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to hide in the onCreate method

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```