# ActionBar Android transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to hide the ActionBar from app and show only the flag "back", or to put transparent, but showing only the back button? I want to remove the white part and put the flag white. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25863690/4410376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try -->

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
yourActionBarid.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
yourActionBarid.setElevation(0);
```

**Note**

Add getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Oooo this works! Thanks!